# Drop db2 Schema priviledges

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have connected to `db2` with the id and password I used to create the Sample database.  I am trying to drop a schema that I accidentally created.
I used the following.

```
SQL> drop schema TGR RESTRICT;
```

where `TGR` is the name of the schema I am trying to drop.

I am getting this error

```
ERROR near line 1:
SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the
required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization
 ID: "DB2ADMIN".  Operation: "DROP SCHEMA". Object: "TGR     ".
```

`DB2ADMIN` is the id that was used to create the Sample database to start with.

I am running DB2 version 10.5 Express-C on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Is the schema empty, are there any tables in that schema? Try `select tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema='TGR'`

Comment: I have a feeling that you're looking for [`ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022036.html)

Comment: data_henrik - I had previously dropped the only table in the schema.

Comment: mustaccio - I am wanting to understand why the drop schema command is failing.